# Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an SQL Command ('SQL Injection')

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, sql-injection, veracode

I have used following method to call stored procedures from my application and it is working perfectly.
The main issue is that when i run veracode on my application, it is giving me following error on `ExecuteReader`,

> "Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an SQL Command ('SQL Injection')"

The reference for resolving the issue is below,

"https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/89.html"

As you can see there are no static queries in my following method and `Parameters.Add` is already being called to add the parameters for the stored procedure.
I have previously resolved this error by following the reference link solution on static queries parameters, but here in the below method there is no query involved so i
am confused how to resolve it.

Can anyone guide me the solution to dissolve this error? I don't want to change my method for calling stored procedures as it will impact my whole production application.

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> callProcForOutput(string procName, Dictionary<string, string> procParam, SqlConnection conn)
{
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> outvalues = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procName, conn))
    {
        procParam.ForEach(x => parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(x.Key, (object)x.Value)));

        command.CommandTimeout = 90;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }            

       
        command.Transaction = TransactionManager.TransManager.Transaction;

       
        SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
        Dictionary<string, object> keyvalues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            keyvalues = Enumerable.Range(0, rdr.FieldCount).ToDictionary(rdr.GetName, rdr.GetValue);
            outvalues.Add(keyvalues);
        }
        rdr.Close();
        return outvalues;
       
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is the code that is being referenced then I don't see where the vulnerability exists.  As you state, you're correctly using parameterised queries.

Comment: A wild guess is that it cannot prove that `procName` cannot be injected.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of dynamic coding. However, the fundamental flexibility of this method is what is causing the issue.

One way of understanding what the scanner is flagging is in terms of 'source to sync'. 'Source' is often user input that should be filtered and validated. 'Sync' is where data is output too, often where other processes read from (synced) which is often a database. This is where the scanner expects to see controls and to see data escaped for persistence.

The fact that the method uses parameters, and the variable is called `procName` may be distracting from the fact that the contents could be **any** *function* or *procedure* or compatible *SQL* or *DDL*. Furthermore, within the scope of the method, the names of the parameters are **not validated or filtered**. Within the scope of this method is where these should be allow-listed and escaped. Thus, **the short reason this method is flagged is because neither the stored procedure nor its parameter names are restricted.**

As was mentioned before, this method allows the calling of any statement. This flexibility may save effort in code creation, this sort of flexibility is not a best practice when interacting along the border between application and database. It is precisely the sort of functionality a pentester would try to detect and exploit. You want to control which SQL and Stored Procs can be called. One pattern used often is to have a single function wrap a single query or procedure, as you mention above, because it is safer. You may find more flexible patterns with frameworks that abstract direct ADO .NET calls like Dapper or Entity Framework.

Another way to think of C# and Security is like it is water. When you put water in a glass, it has surface tension, not only on top, but wherever it touches anything: the glass, the air, or a spoon that you put in it. These are the places that your C# needs to restrict what comes in and goes out. In the middle is where you get to be flexible and squishy :D

I hope this perspective helps when addressing these sorts of issues, especially when flagged by automation that is poor at explaining 'why'.